# Trigger a function in VB.net from LabVIEW Output

Tags: vb.net, labview

I am using [LabVIEW](https://www.ni.com/en-us/shop/labview.html) to monitor/control test conditions. I have a separate WinForm (Using Visual Studio 2019) to control data acquisition.

How can I get LabVIEW to output a "trigger" value to a port in the Windows VB.NET framework? Thereby allowing the data acquisition to commence. In other words how can I get LabVIEW & VB.NET to talk to one another?

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a broad question. There are a number of ways to do this from simply writing to and reading from a file or the registry, to using TCP ports on the computer to communicate. It ay depend on your needs, what you want to communicate and how often.

You can find some options for the TCP-type of communication in [this post](https://forums.ni.com/t5/Developer-Center-Resources/Inter-Application-Communication-using-TCP-and-NET-Remoting/ta-p/3523148?profile.language=en).